# Mathematical boundaries (audio meter)

Tags: coffeescript

I've just been putting together an audio meter by [stacking bootstrap progress bars](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#progress-stacked), and thought there was probably a better way, mathematically / logically, of achieving this.

```
levels = (vumeter) ->
  green = if vumeter % 50 < vumeter then 50 else vumeter
  yellow = if vumeter % 85 < vumeter then 35 else vumeter - 50
  red = if vumeter % 100 < vumeter then 15 else vumeter - 85

  'green': green
  'yellow': yellow
  'red': red
```

Comment: Welcome to CodeReview.SE! You should tell us what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Well the above code works and is done logically (when vumeter is greater than 50, then green is 50 and yellow is the remainder) etc but I suspect this can be done more efficiently..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you want to replicate a classical audio meter (aka green bar grows until 50, then a yellow bar appears on top of green and grows until 85, then a red bar grows from there), then the easiest way to do this is with `min` and `max` functions.

Assuming that vumeter should not be mutated here is the pseudo-code I came up with:

```
green = min(vumeter, 50)
yellow = max(min(vumeter - green, 35), 0)
red = max(min(vumeter - green - yellow, 15), 0)
```

Answer (score 4):

`vumeter % 50 < vumeter` doesn't make much sense to me. For non-negative numbers, this is equivalent to `vumeter > 50`, so you can just use that instead. For negative numbers, this will always return `false`, although it seems like this would be an illegal argument to your function.

@mleyfman provided a great solution. In practice, the code provided achieves something called *clamping*, where you restrict a value to a specified range. You can roll your own `clamp` function like so:

```
clamp = (value, min, max) -> Math.min(Math.max(min, value), max)

levels = (vumeter) ->
  'green'  : clamp(vumeter,  0,  50)
  'yellow' : clamp(vumeter, 50,  85) - 50
  'red'    : clamp(vumeter, 85, 100) - 85
  // or, if you find it more meaningful to provide maxima as parameters rather than ranges:
  'green': clamp(vumeter, 0, 50)
  'yellow': clamp(vumeter - 50, 0, 35)
  'red': clamp(vumeter - 85, 0, 15)
```

Comment: Accepted @mleyfman's answer as I think theirs was first (and have lower rep) but appreciate your response as well and have upvoted it. Both very useful, thanks!